# Regex to check if a word doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net, regex

My test string is contains New Lines.

```
Test<?TEST.
sdasdsadads
Test<?TEST.

Test<?TEST.
```

I want to check if the combination `<?` exists anywhere in the text. If so, my regex should fail.

Any ideas?

ASP.NET web page.\

```
<td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" Height="55px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator11" runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="test" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                                ValidationGroup="Validations" ValidationExpression="^(?![\s\S]*<\?)" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
```

Comment: can you clarify the question and may be give some example?

Comment: Should it be case sensitive or not?

Comment: Did you check [Apple's doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: RegEx can not do **Not Match**. It can only check **Match**

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Of course regexes can do that. Unless you're using a regex engine that hasn't been updated since about 1970.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im : sure regexes can check for non-matching strings. `if re.match(...) == None`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: what is the [nsregularexpression] tag? No tag wiki for it.

Comment: @Li-aungYip: Check the link in Ofer's comment.

Comment: "ASP.NET web page" in the text and "nsregularexpression" in the tags. What are you asking about? iOS, ASP.NET (i.e. server code), JavaScript (i.e. client code), something else?

Comment: @Li-aungYip: no tag wiki? Yes it does. Just no summary.

Answer (score 2):

This is what negative lookahead assertions are for:

```
^(?!.*<\?)
```

matches only if `<?` doesn't occur anywhere in the string. You might want to add `(?s)` at the start if your text can contain newlines.

Comment: When text contains Newline characters how to form the Regex?, tired adding ?s at the start but not working in ASP.NET web page

Comment: @sqlnewbie: It's `(?s)`, not `?s`. And if your regex engine is in fact JavaScript instead of .NET (which it is when you're doing the matching on the client side), then this doesn't work indeed. Instead, use the regex `^(?![\s\S]*<\?`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex to search for a specific word. Instead, just do a plain substring search for that specific word.

In Python, this would look like:

```
def string_contains_test (text):
    lowercase_text = text.lower()
    if 'test' in lowercase_text:
        return True
    else:
        return False

text_1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amur...."
text_2 = "This is a test."

string_contains_test ( text_1 ) # False.
string_contains_test ( text_2 ) # True.
```

Note that case folding (converting a string to upper or lowercase) is evil when done to a Unicode string. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
!Regex.IsMatch(testString, Regex.Escape("<?"))
```

Or even easier:

```
!testString.Contains("<?")
```

Using only a regex (this will work for newlines also):

```
^(?![\s\S]*<\?)
```

Comment: I have tried it but not working Akzen, with new lines, could u check it?

Comment: I tested it using this .net regex tester: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Can you check your test input with the link above? it should use the same Regex engine as the .net framework. Maybe you can post some code from the ASP.net webpage where you are using the regex, to see if we spot an error.

Comment: <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" Height="55px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator11" runat="server"
                                ControlToValidate="test" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"
                                ValidationGroup="Validations" ValidationExpression="^(?![\s\S]*<\?)" EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?!.*(\b(these|are|bad|words)\b)).*$
```

Comment: Why do you recommend this approach over the other expressions previously submitted as answers?